# UICollectionView leaves blank cells while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have built a uicollectionview that shows the thumbnails of images. Every thing works fine until.

I delete a photo from the end of the collection view and scroll to top.

So the problem is when i scroll from bottom back to top it leaves these blank cells. But if i delete from top of collection view and scroll to bottom then it doesnt leave these blank cells.

I dont know what is causing it. I am very sure that the UICollectionViewDataSource are updated properly.

Please help me with this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. Its a bug. Reducing the cell size fixed the problem. I just reduced the cell width and the problem is fixed.